# ArcMap is not opening?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

Tried renaming and deleting the ESRI folder in C:\Users\Mus\AppData\Roaming, no luck... Using Windows 7 SP1 32 bit system. When I start ArcMap 10.3 it shows the the program is initializing and loading document... but nothing opens. But ArcCatalog is working fine. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to open direct to an MXD or to ArcMap itself?

Comment: Have you added any new toolbars or Add-Ins recently?

Comment: Tried both, nothing is working.

Comment: No, didn't add anything.

Comment: But, I installed JDK recently, do you think that can cause this?

Comment: Try creating a startup log and see if the log offers any clues.  See [How To: Create an ArcMap startup log](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000009316)

Comment: I get the following message when i type the arcmap.exe/log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40741/discussion-between-mustafa-and-midavalo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just had a similar issue with 10.4, where it wouldn't load ArcMap and then crash and give no error or indication of what happened. Event viewer and checking logs didn't show anything suspicious. It had to do with python libraries being updated back in December. You can fix this by editing your registry.

Try some of the solutions listed in [Problem: ArcMap crashes during Loading Document launch stage](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012670):

> ArcMap unexpectedly exits during the "Loading Document..." stage on
>   startup. No error code is displayed.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the real problem. Thanks a lot. I have been struggling with this for last 2-3 days. The only thing is, I am using a 32 bit OS and the location of the "2.7" folder in Registry was not exactly at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7 , in my case it was at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7 . I changed it there and now its working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked! Super annoying when there's no helpful error code to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3):

Just go to C:\Users*%%%*\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates
=> Delete "Normal" file (Or rename it).
And Open ArcMap.
I Did and succeeded. ^_^
Hope it is useful for you!

Answer (score 1):

try remove PYTHONHOME in environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with 10.7 and the issue had to do with the PYTHONHOME environment variable.  I installed Python 3.7 for some other work I was doing and that apparently confused ArcMap on loading.  I completely removed PYTHONHOME from my Environment Variables and it fixed the issue.  I will have to try to find another resolution as I will need to use 3.7 again but it's fixed for now.